# C# datetime xml rowfilter

Tags: c#, xml, date, datetime, rowfilter

I know this question was asked before, but the answers were not clear.

I have an xml storing the date as plain text in "dd/mm/yyyy ssss"

When i tried to use dataset.rowfilter().  The input can be adjusted to either dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy, but the comparison from rowfilter only sees the comparison style as mm/dd/yyyy.  Maybe this has something to do with the American date and British date difference.

The StartDate and EndDate is from datetimepicker.  it doesn't need to be parsed.. It is within the rowsfilter call that does the comparison like mm/dd/yyyy instead of user-defined dd/mm/yyyy.

```
filter = " (Date >= #" +
     StartDate.value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") +
     "# And Date <= #" +
     EndDate.value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") +
     "# ) ";
```

if i do the above, the comparison will not see for example  13/01/2018 as a date.  It gives an exception error saying it is an invalid date. (**This parsing error comes from rowfilter comparison, not the parsing the date**)  As it is reading it as mm/dd/yyyy.

Is there anyway to use rowfilter properly to force their comparison method or do I have to change my entire xml data storage to "MM/dd/yyyy" to use rowfilter.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

> You are using wrong way of conversion

That's why it's throwing error.

So if you need to tell compiler that you have specific date-time format and convert accordingly you have to

Use [DateTime.ParseExact Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx)

Like

```
DateTime.ParseExact(startTime,"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mmtt", null);
```

This will parse your string in format you defined not the one which system defined.

**Update:**

```
filter = " (Date >= #" +
         Convert.ToDateTime(txtFromDate.Text).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") +
         "# And Date <= #" +
         Convert.ToDateTime(txtToDate.Text).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") +
         "# ) ";
```

Comment: it is not the conversion for the starttime or endtime..  It is in the Date in the dataset that's default to that to dd/mm/yyyy format.  The start and endTime did show as dd/mm/yyyy.  but the comparison method within rowfilter uses mm/dd/yyyy as comparison..

Comment: @ChelvanMei then you can change your query like i mentioned in updated answer.

Comment: Actually Dave,  the startdate and enddate is from datetimepicker.. i used that and .value to get the DateTime, the conversion has no problem.. It is within the .rowfilter comparison that takes it as mm/dd/yyyy instead of my dd/mm/yyyy.. That's my problem.   Even if i use Convert.ToDateTime(txtFromDate.Text).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy").. it does not work as my Date >= #.. where i store my data is in dd/MM/yyyy format.  so basically,  rowfilter is comparing ..  mm/dd/yyyy against dd/mm/yyyy.

Comment: I may have to go to my Dataset and change the string date format programmically from dd/MM/yyyy to MM/dd/yyyy before calling rowfilter.. I guess that's the only way.

Comment: yea i think so.

Answer (score 0):

Ok Here is what i did..

I cheated a little.  I wrote a Date swapper with string manipulation to swap the dd/mm/yyyy to mm/dd/yyyy or vis vera.   Before calling the .rowfilter.

I turned the dataview to datatable,  change all the datetime column string date using the date swapper, then do a rowfilter sort, after having the result, I call the date swapper again to convert it back.. Long process, but it seems that's the only way as .rowfilter uses only mm/dd/yyyy for >= <= comparison.

Thanks Chelvan.